# How to verify if values are updated or not by API using groovy in soap ui

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am using soapui and groovy for api automation and assertion.

Have one API which updates user profile data. i.e update username,firstname,lastname etc.

What is best way to verify that if data is updated or not after run update api. In groovy is there any way by which I can store previous data from API response then run update api and again check response and finally compare previous response and latest one?

What I have tried it comparing values which I am going to sent via API and values which API returns. If both equal then assume that values update. But this seems not perfect way to check update function.

[image: Update API Example]

Comment: Provide more details as update request and response etc ? or how you query to find if the data is updated?

Comment: @Rao - For now I am not using any query or database interaction. I just match values I set as parameters , Send post request and compare values from response using ==. That't it.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138414/room-for-rao-and-helping-hands

Comment: @Rao - I have added screenshot to show request and response. What generally I do for now is comparing department name string from request and response to make sure if it is updated or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a test case level custom property, say *DEPARTMENT_NAME* and value as needed.

Add a `Script Assertion` for the same request test step with below script:

```
//Check if the response is received
assert context.response, 'Response is null or empty'

//Parse text to json
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)
log.info "Department name from response ${json.data.name}"

assert json.data.name == context.expand('${#TestCase#DEPARTMENT_NAME}'), 'Department name is not matched'
```

You may also edit the request, and add the value as `${#TestCase#DEPARTMENT_NAME}` instead of current fixed value `XAPIAS Department`. So that you can just change the value of department name at test case level property, the same is sent in the request and the same is verified in the response.

Comment: Getting error on this line : **context.response, 'Response is null or empty'**, Says expecting EOF. That should be assert I think.

Comment: That is because, there might not have response. You should run the request and script assertion would run automatically. Please try it again.

Comment: I have updated the answer with small fix, can you re-try please. You may also join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138414/room-for-rao-and-helping-hands

Answer (score -1):

Use JDBC teststep to run query directly into database:

Use Xpath assertion to Validate your Update API
Assertion 1
**/Results/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/FirstName**
Expected result
*Updated FirstName*
Assertion 2
**/Results/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/LastName**
*Updated Last Name*

In our project we do it in this way:

1. First we execute all the APIs.
2. Then we Validate all the new/updated data in database in DB Validation testcase.

Works well in highly integrated environment as well.